# django datefield auto_now = true dont work

Tags: django

I have this table in my model, i just want that if the data is updated the `modifyDate` field will automatict updated.

note: ***i am not using the adminsite to update data***

```
class FmCustomerEmployeeSupplier(models.Model):

    dateSubmitted = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    middleInitial = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    bodyTemperature = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    modifyDate = models.DateField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    modifyBy = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)

    @property
    def is_past_due(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return date.today() > self.modifyDate
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "50. Customer's List of Employees, Suppliers and visitors"
```

Comment: How are you saving the object? Using `FmCustomerEmployeeSupplier.save()`?

Comment: yes, and if that data is updated specially that bodyTemperature , the modifyDate field will automatic updated as well

Comment: `auto_now_add` is only set on creation. Did you run your migrations?

Comment: yes, i already run migrations, in the field `modifyDate` , the date will automatic  updated when the data is update

Comment: So what’s the issue then?

Comment: the `modifyDate` dont work, the date didnt updated when the data is updated

Comment: You should edit your question to show an example of when saving updates the `modifyDate` and an example when it doesn't. You're saying if `bodyTemperature` was updated then `modifyDate` is also updated. But you also said `modifyDate` doesn't work, the date didn't update. So which is it?